# how to upload a pdf document in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

how to upload a pdf document in Laravel  field name is `RESUME` and folder create din `PUBLIC->RESUME`

```
protected function create(array $data)
{
    $file_extention = $data['RESUME']->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $file_name = time().rand(99,999).'RESUME.'.$file_extention;
    $file_path = $data['RESUME']->move(public_path().'/users/image',$file_name);

    return User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'mobile' => $data['mobile'],
        'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
        'file_path' => $RESUME
    ]);
          
    
}
```

Comment: said in a whisper "why are you shouting at us?"

Comment: pls edit your question to let us know exactly whats wrong with your code

Comment: Welcome, to improve your experience on SO please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), 
an [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), then look at the 
[Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), 
the [perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/), 
how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) AGAIN

Comment: EDITED Giacomo M

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have already uploaded a file with its name. If you want to specific name will be file name, then change  `$file->storeAs($filePath, $fileName='RESUME', 'uploads');`.If you have any queries, feel free to comment below. Thanks

```
protected function create(array $data){
 $request = request();

 $profileImage = $request->file('resumes');
 $profileImageSaveAsName = time() . Auth::id() . "-profile." . $profileImage->getClientOriginalExtension();

 $upload_path = 'resumes/';
 $resumes= $upload_path . $profileImageSaveAsName;
 $success = $profileImage->move($upload_path, $profileImageSaveAsName);


  return User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        'dob' => $data['dob'],
        'resumes' => $resumes,
    ]);
}
```

Comment: can I paste the same like this  Rashed Zaman

Comment: if I put it like this its showing error Rashed Zaman

Comment: can you share the WhatsApp number with full code  Rashed Zaman